# Take part of URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm new here, I save images in firebase, and I know what the `url` address of the image is. Inside the url there is also the name of the image.
For example:

```
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/socialproject-c465b.appspot.com/o/no-img.png?alt=media"
```

The name of the image is:
***no-img.png***

I wrote down a code to get the name of the image along with its extension. I do not understand why I do not succeed.
I only get the extension of the `.png` image, but not the name of the image.

The code:

```js
const fileName = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/socialproject-c465b.appspot.com/o/4581221354541.png?alt=media";
const regEx = /[0-9]*\.(?:jpg|png)/;
const match = fileName.match(regEx);
const imageName = match[0];
console.log(imageName);
```

Comment: I just ran your code and got `4581221354541.png` as a result, isn't it what you expect to have?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, this is the result I want to get, I only get .png
Did you change anything in the code?

Comment: I pasted your code in the chrome console without changing anything

Comment: Your regex works fine. No change required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do not understand why my code does not work

Comment: Your regex matches only numbers inside file name. It will not work with `no-image.png`

Comment: thank you for help, what can i do to fix it? i try to do it for hours, but this no works for me

Answer (score 3):

Your regex works for numbers but you could use the URL API to take any filename

```js
const getFileName = url =>  new URL(url).pathname.split("/").pop();

const url1 = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/socialproject-c465b.appspot.com/o/no-img.png?alt=media";

console.log(getFileName(url1));

const url2 = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/socialproject-c465b.appspot.com/o/4581221354541.png?alt=media";

console.log(getFileName(url2));
```

Comment: thank you for help: i try to use this url: ""https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/socialproject-c465b.appspot.com/o/no-img.png?alt=media"", and this dont work for me

Comment: Yes it does. See updated snippet